# How to use JPA findBy on column mapped by @OneToMany annotation in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have this model which call invoice, it's contains a @one to many annotation

this is my model :

```
    public class Invoice {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private int id;
        @Column(name = "serial_number")
        private long serialNumber;
        @Column(name = "status")
        private String status;
        @Column(name = "created_date")
        private Timestamp createdDate;
        @Column(name = "is_deleted")
        private boolean isDeleted;
        @ManyToOne
        @JsonIgnore
        @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
        private Customer customer;
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
        private Employee employee;
        @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="invoice")
        private Set <InvoiceHistory> invoiceHistories;
        @OneToMany (mappedBy = "invoice")
        private Set <InvoiceItem> quantity; 
}
```

How can i find by all invoices which have the employee id  = xxxxx?

Comment: Take a look to the list of allowed **Query methods** https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods in your case, should be `List<Invoice> findByEmployee(Employee employee)`

Comment: and i send employee in the parameter ? not just id ?

Comment: If you have the `Employee`'s identifier instead of the entity (assuming you have added in `Employee` the following identifier definition:  `@Id private Integer id`) the suitable method is `List<Invoice> findByEmployeeId(Integer employeeId)`.

Answer (score 1):

use custom query to get invoices

```
Query("select x from  Invoice  x  where x.employee.employeeId=:empId")
List<Invoice > getAllInvoicesByEmpId(Long empId) ;
```

Or you can get all invoices belonging to the employee but from the employee itself by loading the employee By id  based  on   OneToMany  Relation in Employee Model  but  this way "Not Recommended "

Comment: I did this but it's returning an empty list

Comment: If the PK in `Employee` was defined as `id` instead of `employeeId` (or mapped to that in a suitable way), then provided query won't work

Comment: in a simple way     @doctore I don't know  how PK defined the so I expected that PK mapped to employed  ,

Comment: @TaliaDianal  could you share a screenshot of Db  for Invoice Table  
or if you are sure that there is data 
you can use the other Way  but there are simple  changes in  the mapping 
Steps : 
1) add EmployeeId in invoice Entity  : 
 @Column(name = "employee_id")
private Long employeeId;


2) change this Line "      @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")"  To be  
           @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id",insertable=false , updateble=false )


3) change the query 
Query("select x from  Invoice  x  where x.employeeId=:empId")
List<Invoice > getAllInvoicesByEmpId(Long empId) ;